# Disabling "oh-my-zsh" SVN completion

Tags: bash, svn, zsh, autocomplete

I am using Zsh version: **4.3.11** with the  [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) framework.

When coupled with "oh-my-zsh", Zsh will attempt to autocomplete SVN (and Git for that matter) commands when the TAB key is pressed during a command. Since it obviously does some parsing-magic behind the curtains, autocompleting SVN commands in a huge repository introduces a significant delay.

```
svn add a[TAB]
* ~2-3 second delay *
svn add apps/
```

This is driving me to the edge, and after a couple of months with nothing but praise left over for Zsh, I have temporarily reverted to Bash, as being unable to use the shell in one specific repository is just ridiculous.

**Note:**
There are two additional factors here, and although I'm unsure of their significance, I'll list them anyways:

- This is done over SSH
- Normal filename-autocompletion is completely instant. Only filename-autocompletion during SVN commands is laggy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure, that is not the nice way, but you can overwrite the `svn`completion with

```
compdef '_files -g "*"' svn
```

After that, `zsh` will only offer files

```
% svn     
tags in context :completion::complete:svn::
    globbed-files  (_files)
```

instead of the dedicated and time consuming `_svn` completions:

```
% svn 
tags in context :completion::complete:svn::
    argument-1 options  (_arguments _svn _subversion)
tags in context :completion::complete:svn:argument-1:
    commands  (_svn _subversion)
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot. I have tried various compdef settings so far without luck, but not this one. :) Gonna check it out when I get to work tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: This completely did the trick. The only itch from using Zsh is hereby eliminated, thanks a load :)